# Ignore warnings from framework headers on OS X

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, gcc, clang

When including external library headers in my C++ project I can use `-isystem` flag instead of `-I` (at least for GCC or Clang) to mark particular include directory as system libraries directory. This way compiler won't report any warnings regarding the code of external libraries.

Is there any way to do this with OS X framework headers, which are not passed to compiler using `-I` flags but using `-F` flag pointing to the directory framework is located in?

**Example**

Compilation command:

```
clang++ -F/Users/user/CustomFrameworks -o test.o -c test.cpp
```

test.cpp

```
#include <Framework/Header.h>
// ....
```

Framework structure:

```
$ ls /Users/user/CustomFrameworks
Framework.framework
$ ls /Users/user/CustomFrameworks/Framework.framework/Headers
Header.h
```

How to ignore warnings from `Header.h`?

**If only possible I'd rather not put any compiler-specific pragmas in my code.**

Comment: In another dimension, where compilers meet usability and conventions, I'm sure there is just `-fsystem` flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-iframework` flag. Sometimes reading [man-pages](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/gcc.1.html) helps...

Comment: Yeah, I somehow end up reading only clang's docs as it is current default Xcode compiler. Shame clang does not support this flag (yet?).

Comment: Have you tried it? The clang man-page is very incomplete and most of the gcc flags are supported.